# HTTPS Secured works only on home page not the next page

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, spring-security, amazon-elb

I am deploying a spring boot webapplication in AWS EC2 instance on port 80 and the home page is displayed as Secured When I click on the link like user login or admin login the browser shows it as Not Secured.What should I do to make my whole application secured.

Below is my code which I am using from a site,I am new to spring security,Please help.

Home.html

```
<div class="starter-template">
                <h1>Spring Boot Web Thymeleaf + Spring Security</h1>
                <h2>1. Visit <a th:href="@{/admin}">Admin page (Spring Security protected, Need Admin Role)</a></h2>
                <h2>2. Visit <a th:href="@{/user}">User page (Spring Security protected, Need User Role)</a></h2>
                <h2>3. Visit <a th:href="@{/about}">Normal page</a></h2>
            </div>


    @Configuration
    // http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-security.html
    // Switch off the Spring Boot security configuration
    //@EnableWebSecurity
    public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

        // roles admin allow to access /admin/**
        // roles user allow to access /user/**
        // custom 403 access denied handler
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http.csrf().disable()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/about").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("USER")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .logout()
                    .permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler);
        }


            @Autowired
            public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

                auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                        .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER")
                        .and()
                        .withUser("admin").password("password").roles("ADMIN");
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?Is the issue in the code or my AWS Configuration

Comment: I figured out what the issue is the login page requires authentication before it becomes secured.Is my assumption right as per the code?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by setting application.properties to the below

server.use-forward-headers=true